# Replying in a thread using gmail api users.messages: send is not working

Tags: javascript, nodemailer, google-api-nodejs-client

Am using nodemailer to send mails. But reply functionality is not working as expected. below is the mailOptions am using during reply operation. Mail is received but not shown in a same thread

```
new MailComposer({
      from: fromEmail,
      to: toAddress,
      inReplyTo: <some unique string here @mail.gmail.com>(it is a messageId from the mail am replying to),
      references: <some unique string here @mail.gmail.com>(same as inReplyTo),
      subject(same as the message am replying to),
      html,
      headers: {
        replyTo: toAddress,
        'In-Reply-To': <some unique string here @mail.gmail.com>(same as inReplyTo),
        references: <some unique string here @mail.gmail.com>(same as inReplyTo) 
      },
    });
...
api.send({
    userId: 'me',
    auth,
    requestBody: {
      raw: encodedMessage
      threadId: 'threadId from the message am replying to'
    }
  });
```

What am i missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that in the mailOptionConfig that the subject of the mail you are replying to have the same subject. If you change the subject, then a new thread will be created.